# ko foreach binding inside <script>

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can I use ko foreach inside script tag?

I did the following:

```
<script type="text/html" id="row_hdr">
   <!-- ko foreach: rowLevelButtons -->
      <some code>
   <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

I expected the code inside to get executed as number of items in array rowLevelButtons but got Reference error : rowLevelButtons is not defined.

Any pointer?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `foreach` in a template (script tag). It just can't find `rowLevelButtons` in the binding context when rendering it.

Comment: But I checked ,and found rowLevelButtons getting populated and accessible to other parts of the code.

Comment: To other parts but not to this one. Could you add your viewmodel and the html that uses this template?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing the rest of your code and view model, but it is likely that it's down to a context scoping issue. If it can't find it there you can try using `$root` if it's an array at the root of your view model:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.rowLevelButtons -->
   <some code>
<!-- /ko -->
```